# Hover Menu border bottom

Tags: html, css, border

My `border` is to bad offbeat. How can I fix it?

```css
#navigation-menu ul.sf-menu > li > a:hover span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-top-menu" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">
  <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-18"><a href=""><span>Accueil</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-150"><a href="http://#"><span>Présentation</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-152" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-152"><a href="http://#"><span>Référence</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-32"><a href="impression-offset/"><span>Impression offset</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-29"><a href="/impression-numerique-grand-format/" class="sf-with-ul"><span>Impression numerique grand format</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="float: none; width: 12.7143em; display: none;">
      <li id="menu-item-151" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-151" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;"><a href="http://#" style="float: none; width: auto;"><span>Fabrication publicitaire</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-30"><a href="/impression-numerique-petit-format/"><span>Impression numerique petit format</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-22"><a href="contact"><span>Contact</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: from the classes this is a superfish menu, so it is missing CSS

Answer (score 0):

This would work for all links

```
a span {
text-decoration: none;
}

a span:hover {
border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

Further narrowing your style

```
.menu-item-30 a span:hover {
border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#main-top-menu > li > a:hover span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-top-menu" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">
  <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-18"><a href=""><span>Accueil</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-150"><a href="http://#"><span>Présentation</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-152" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-152"><a href="http://#"><span>Référence</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-32"><a href="impression-offset/"><span>Impression offset</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-29"><a href="/impression-numerique-grand-format/" class="sf-with-ul"><span>Impression numerique grand format</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="float: none; width: 12.7143em; display: none;">
      <li id="menu-item-151" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-151" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;"><a href="http://#" style="float: none; width: auto;"><span>Fabrication publicitaire</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-30"><a href="/impression-numerique-petit-format/"><span>Impression numerique petit format</span></a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-22"><a href="contact"><span>Contact</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

On hover red line comes as border , but blue line still remains, to remove that add `text-decoration: none;`  to `#main-top-menu > li > a`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use `text-decoration: none;` for your `<a>` elements and apply the border to the span (both normal and during hovers).

http://codepen.io/johnniebenson/pen/GZVJEE

```
ul.sf-menu > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

ul.sf-menu > li > a span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

ul.sf-menu > li > a:hover span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cc0000;
}
```